# Get number of hours between two DateTimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I'm trying to create an if statement that checks if there has been less than 48 hours since the creation of an order, i.e. COrderDate ,and there is still more than 48 hours until the delivery date. i.e. CDeliveryDate

```
 if (order.COrderDate < 48 hours since DateTime.Now 
     && DateTime.Now < 48 hours from order.CDeliveryDate)
```

Comment: DateTime.Now.AddHours(-48)

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract one `DateTime` from another and get a [`TimeSpan`] result which represents an amount of time. For example:

```
var timeSinceOrderDate = order.COrderDate - DateTime.Now;
```

You can then check that `TimeSpan` to see how many hours, minutes, days, etc. it contains.

```
if(timeSinceOrderDate.TotalHours >= 48)
```

This will tell you much time is left until the end of the universe:

```
var timeUntilEndOfTheUniverse = DateTime.MaxValue - DateTime.Now;
```